# Generate class-diagram from java each build

Tags: java, gradle, uml, reverse-engineering

For several reasons I need to generate the UML-class diagram from a specific java package. I know there are several tools available to do the job once, but I want to have included in my gradle build. After running the thing there should be something like an image.

How would you do it?

Comment: First do it manually... then automate.

Comment: Great idea! I already use IntelliJ for it (works well) but sometimes I forget to generate and then image is not updated. Thats why I want to automate the generating.

Answer (score 0):

I would integrate [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/).  You'd have to also integrate [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/) to generate the image file, but PlantUML seems like a very simple framework for generating the intermediate metadata file.

Comment: Have you seen a working example which does the trick? some gradle plugin?